# Interoperability with SwiftyChrono from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift3, frameworks, language-interoperability

I'm trying to use the [SwiftyChrono](https://github.com/quire-io/SwiftyChrono) swift library from an Objective-C project. Since it's using a `struct` instead of a `class` (amongst many other Swift only features), I'm unable to make it work.

Given I am not in the position of moving all our Objective-C code to Swift, what are my options? Would writing a second Swift framework work, one that sits in between our app and SwiftyChrono and serves as a wrapper? Would that even work? I'm guessing if this new Swift framework was dumb enough to only perform a single function in 'Swift Land', it would play well with Objective-C?

I haven't dealt with inter-op and it really feels like a losing battle. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The path of least resistance was to update the library's code and expose it to Obj-C.